# How to link My Documents folder to the logical Documents folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, documents, my-documents

In windows 7 the My Documents folder resides under the logical Documents folder on the left side of Windows Explorer.
A friend of mine clicked on My Documents and (silly him) erased it by deleting it. Of couse the My Documents folder is still under C:\Users\user\Documents.

How do I link My Documents back to Documents?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7 (and Vista before that), the "My Documents" folder is actually a **Junction Point** (or **symbolic link**) that resolves to the new folder called Documents.

Assuming he deleted the "My Documents" junction point, here's what I'd do:

1. Open a Command Window as Administrator (CMD.EXE)
2. `CD C:\Users\YourUserName`
3. `DIR /A`
4. **If you see *My Documents* in the list, stop here, because something is wrong**
5. `mklink /J "C:\Users\YourUserName\My Documents" "C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents"`
6. Back in Windows Explorer, browse to your home folder (C:\Users\YourUserName)
7. Confirm that the My Documents folder is back where it belongs and functions correctly.

Be careful to keep the quotation marks and spaces exactly as you see them in the `commands`, while replacing *YourUserName* with your login name for Windows.  Each command goes on one line, even though you might see some line wrapping above.

Good luck!

Comment: both C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents and C:\Users\YourUserName\My Documents are there, but when I enter Documents everything's in place and when I enter My Documents it's empty. I guess the Junction Point got messed up. What should I do? Can I reroute it?

Comment: Try removing the new My Documents folder you created, then try the Restore Default Libraries feature (which I list in my next post below.)

Answer (score 1):

Something else that might help - try the built-in Windows 7 feature **Restore Default Libraries**.  In Explorer, point to the Libraries folder, Right-Click, Restore default libraries.

This may recover the default **My Documents** folder link as well.

[image: Screen Shot]